# will_paginate redirecting to root path

Tags: resources, root, will-paginate, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 application (with Spree 0.40 attached).

In my `ProductsController`, action `index`, I have the list of products and below `will_paginate` helper.

The problem is that the helper is rendering links to `localhost:3000/?page=x` instead of `localhost:3000/products/?page=`x

I have `resources :products` in my routes file.

Any idea what is causing this odd behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the `root :to` from the `routes.rb` of the Spree gem to solve the problem.